# couldn't find the difference between two date in another textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

**my date format is dd/mm/yyyy and calculate this format**

**here a script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function GetDays() {

    var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("sdate").value);
    var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("edate").value);
    var difference = edate - sdate;
    return Math.round(difference / 1000 * 3600 * 24);
  }

  function cal() {

    document.getElementById("numdays2").value = GetDays();

  }
</script>
```

Comment: your description of the problem is not clear enough, I wonder if you describe it more.

Comment: calculate no of days between two dates

Comment: but date format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Regarding date operations, I find very convenient to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) if you don't mind using an external library. Making your own operations on dates seems easy at first, but can be quite tedious...

Answer (score 1):

you need to get time from date and then do the calculation

```
var date1 = new Date("06/30/2019"); 
var date2 = new Date("07/30/2019"); 

// To calculate the time difference of two dates
var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 

// To calculate the no. of days between two dates
var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24); 

//To display the final no. of days (result)
console.log("Total number of days between dates  <br>"
               + date1 + "<br> and <br>" 
               + date2 + " is: <br> " 
               + Difference_In_Days);
```

Comment: but i can display value in textbox

Comment: document.getElementById("numdays2").value = Difference_In_Days;

Answer (score 0):

at the first place identifiers are wrong
at the second place use getTime function to get milliseconds
at the third place add brackets to evaluation expression to get difference in days

```
var difference = dropdt.getTime() - pickdt.getTime();
return Math.round(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Comment: and add brackets difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24)

Comment: @HitendraPatil please check this https://codepen.io/dimoff66/pen/GRgKdXW?editors=0001

Comment: my date format is dd/mm/yyyy and you are using yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: @HitendraPatil, it has nothing to do with my code, new Date doesnt accept your format, i changed my example, now it works correctly with your format https://codepen.io/dimoff66/pen/GRgKdXW?editors=0002